# How to design a UIScrollView in storyboard with iOS 7's new automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets feature?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard

When I enable `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` (or Adjust Scroll View Insets in my Storyboard) on my view controller and place a scroll view in the view controller, any controls I add to the scroll view are either adjusted at runtime to be in the wrong places, or some of them are not editable at design time.

In other words, there are these three options, each with its own drawback:

1. If you place a view below the navigation bar (e.g. y=64), it will be moved 64 points down at run time, and not appear in the correct location (i.e. the location will be offset from the bottom of the navigation bar by 64 points).
2. If you place a view behind the navigation bar (e.g. y=0), it won't be visible nor editable at design time, but it will appear in the correct location.
3. If you disable automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, you will have to manually update the contentInset properties.

What is the best way to work with a scroll view in a storyboard when `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to do this is to stick with option 2, where you place controls behind the navigation bar.

To make them editable, select the view controller in the storyboard, and in the **Attributes Inspector**, set **Top Bar to None** temporarily (or permanently).

[image]

This will allow you to access the top controls at design time, while still causing the scroll view to adjust its insets accordingly.